# (discord.js/discord js) Is there a way to store current channel/category permissions and then reapply after an event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

**Backstory**

So, basically what I'm trying to do is using YT, I saw a lockdown command that locks down every channel in the guild once we type "!lockdown" by overwriting the channel permissions for certain roles but if we unlock the channels, everyone is able to type in other channels as permission gets overwritten to SEND message.

**Trying to achieve**

What I'm trying to achieve is that once we type "!lockdown", it stores the current permissions and then reapply them after I type "!unlock", I'm pretty sure it's possible but I can't figure out how. Any sorts of help will be appreciated!

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may store the permissions of each channel in an object or an array or a database (more efficiency since the bot can be offline between both !lockdown and !unlock).
Then get the datas by a key as the id of each channel to get their permissions and do waht you want.